# How to decrypt a encrypted AES key using RSA private key

Tags: java, base64, aes, rsa

I have an encrypted string (AES key) which is already encrypted using RSA, and I would like to decrypt it using the Private Key that I have.

I have implemented the following code in Java Eclipse:

```
StringBuilder pkcs8Lines = new StringBuilder();
    BufferedReader rdr = new BufferedReader(new StringReader(P_K));
    String line;
    while ((line = rdr.readLine()) != null) {
        pkcs8Lines.append(line);
    }

    // Remove the "BEGIN" and "END" lines, as well as any whitespace

    String pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Lines.toString();
    pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Pem.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
    pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Pem.replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
    pkcs8Pem = pkcs8Pem.replaceAll("\\s+","");

    // Base64 decode the result

  
    byte [] pkcs8EncodedBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(pkcs8Pem);

    // extract the private key

    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(pkcs8EncodedBytes);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
 
    
    String encryptedtxt = "AprF9N/CWpReruoPb798Ncwsb5KFYO6BCH0BxeeB47dKXLMd50LSS9f07vpgw4TJRZAKfQxZgUse+laoxa0F8L6EL491ZHu50HBdONmo8iWyX1B7jYdzvlQTHxYHCUQTMqy9sCDEI0ihNqcIZFPQN3NtYyjALZ5pHHmkUvZc5E4tRRBvwSpoL2ilZdsMa6CotHtGmyB+anBXIkoJE5XfpxvOd1HtfcdEh5I+cl8fBXNq+hD3LvjMlIZzpCW5blc4dHIaMuCfdE5EV+BHW9ZK8O+3HMfnONyiFPJ+W5i8YRZ0BbbhPqJJYmyqiZLcFFAs8r4ulSE6Mf9Rcb+TanTnMQ==";
    

    String plainText = null;
    
      final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
      cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privKey);
      byte[] decoded = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encryptedtxt);
      byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(decoded);
      plainText = new String(decrypted);
    
    System.out.println("Decrypted plaintext: \n\n" + plainText);
```

Running this gave me this gibberish text:

> 4§ˆZ<ïïØ?žç,X?`@fˆH?ÍáxÖšï†˜=

I tried online tools and I obtained another gibberish text:

> 4��Z<��ؐ��,X\�`@f�H���x֚=

Where is the problem?

Comment: I don't think there is a problem with your code, but you are trying to print out an AES key as a string. An AES key is usually 16/24/32 bytes long and the byte array is filled with values of (each) 0..255 (x00 to xFF). Don't try to print out the pure byte array but use it for decryption. If you should need to printout the key use a "byte array to hex string" or a "base64 encoded string".

Comment: Hi Michael, 

Can you give a simple line of command to to this base64 encoding to print it as string?

Comment: There's no point in printing it at all since an AES key just a (in this case) 32-byte random-ish value. What is it you expect to see?

Comment: Base64 usage: "import java.util.Base64;", then "Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(input);" where input is your byte array containing the key

Comment: Thank you, problem solved.